# Fortigate device string parsing using shlex, and split

Tags: python, string

Consider a Fortigate config like

```
config firewall policy
    edit 168
        set name "policy 168"
        set uuid 14435052-3097-4d70-98c7-1dd2d60e229f
        set srcintf "jimmylin__1688"
        set dstintf "port1"
        set srcaddr "address__jimmylin__10.100.168.11/32"
        set dstaddr "all"
        set action accept
        set schedule "always"
        set service "ALL"
        set comments "\"customer\": \"Jimmy Lin\""
        set nat enable
        set ippool enable
        set poolname "ippool__jimmylin__168.100.168.11"
    next
end
```

(This is a .conf, like a **plain text** file)

Say the file is living in /conf/, named firewall_policy.conf.
We want to get it into python so then we can do all the data-processing things around it, So we do

```
>>> with open(file='/conf/firewall_policy.conf', mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
>>>     lines = f.read().splitlines()
```

Now, let's look deeper into it.

```
>>> lines[2]
'        set name "policy 168"'
>>> print(lines[2])
        set name "policy 168"
>>> lines[10]
'        set service "ALL"'
>>> print(lines[10])
        set service "ALL"
>>> lines[11]
'        set comments "\\"customer\\": \\"Jimmy Lin\\""'
>>> print(lines[11])
        set comments "\"customer\": \"Jimmy Lin\""
```

We'll want something like

```
>>> def parse(string):
...     # some string-parsing things
...     return string
...
>>> parse(lines[2])
['set', 'name', '"policy 168"']
>>> parse(lines[10])
['set', 'service', '"ALL"']
>>> parse(lines[11])
['set', 'comments', '"\\"customer\\": \\"Jimmy Lin\\""'']
```

If we simply use

```
>>> def parse(string):
...    return string.split()
...
```

Then we will get

```
>>> parse(lines[2])
['set', 'name', '"policy', '168"']
```

Obviously that is not we want.

If we try shlex — Simple lexical analysis, a module in [The Python Standard Library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html)

```
>>> from shlex import split as shlex_split
>>> def parse(string):
...    return shlex_split(string)
...
```

Then we will get

```
>>> parse(lines[2])
['set', 'name', 'policy 168']
```

That's great, and we can join them back together by

```
>>> from shlex import join as shlex_join
>>> shlex_join(parse(lines[2]))
"set name 'policy 168'"
```

That's almost the same as the original string, but the double quotes around **policy 168** became single quotes. It's acceptable though.

But when it comes to **lines[10]**

```
>>> parse(lines[10])
['set', 'name', 'ALL']
>>> shlex_join(parse(lines[10]))
'set service ALL'
```

The double quotes just disappear, because **ALL** is not a string containing space, and shlex doesn't **think** it is needed to add quotes around it.

I looked up the shlex documentation and it is a parameter called **posix** to use with.

```
>>> from shlex import split as shlex_split
>>> def parse(string):
...    return shlex_split(string, posix=False)
...
>>> parse(lines[2])
['set', 'service', '"ALL"']
```

And we can simply use the built-in **join** to turn it back.

```
>>> ' '.join(parse(lines[2]))
'set service "ALL"'
```

But when it comes to **lines[11]**, that is not the case.

```
>>> ' '.join(parse(lines[11]))
['set', 'comments', '"\\"', 'customer\\":', '\\"Jimmy', 'Lin\\""']
```

I think that is the different way of parsing a string between **Forti** devices and the **shlex** module.
Forti device is seeing something like

```
'set comments \'"customer": "Jimmy Lin"\''
```

set comments ""customer": "Jimmy Lin""

and shlex is seeing something like

```
'set comments "\\"customer\\":  \\"Jimmy Lin\\""'
```

If we use **.replace('\"', ''')**, it will seem better

```
>>> lines[11].replace('\\"', '\'')
'        set comments "\'customer\': \'Jimmy Lin\'"'
>>> parse(lines[11].replace('\\"', '\''))
['set', 'comments', '"\'customer\': \'Jimmy Lin\'"']
```

But this is a dirty way, if there are more escape characters or more complicated nested things, I think it may fail, and the **join** part also not correct

```
>>> ' '.join(parse(lines[11].replace('\\"', '\'')))
'set comments "\'customer\': \'Jimmy Lin\'"'
```

Is there a solution to make these parsing process correct and clean.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want. Sorry, i am not making any function for each line but parsing all in one for loop. You can insert that for loop in to a function if you want. Code commented for futher information.

```
# coding: utf-8

import shlex

with open(file='firewall_policy.conf', mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

for i in range(len(lines)):
    line = lines[i].strip() # stripping each line because there are some spaces
    if line.startswith('set'): # checking whether it starts with the 'set' word
        if '\\' in line:
            lexer1 = shlex.shlex(line, posix=True) # posix stays true
            print(list(lexer1))
        else:
            lexer2 = shlex.shlex(line) # else another lexer
            lexer2.quotes = '"' # quotes are preserved
            lexer2.whitespace_split = True # using whitespaces to split
            print(list(lexer2))
    else:
        pass
```

Output:

```
['set', 'name', '"policy 168"']
['set', 'uuid', '14435052-3097-4d70-98c7-1dd2d60e229f']
['set', 'srcintf', '"jimmylin__1688"']
['set', 'dstintf', '"port1"']
['set', 'srcaddr', '"address__jimmylin__10.100.168.11/32"']
['set', 'dstaddr', '"all"']
['set', 'action', 'accept']
['set', 'schedule', '"always"']
['set', 'service', '"ALL"']
['set', 'comments', '"customer": "Jimmy Lin"']
['set', 'nat', 'enable']
['set', 'ippool', 'enable']
['set', 'poolname', '"ippool__jimmylin__168.100.168.11"']
```

The only problem here is the `\` are gone. But, all other things are good. This is as far as i can solve using `shlex` . Apparently, the argument `posix = True` must be passed in `Python 3.8.x .

Alternative working solution with `Regex` only.

```
import re


def quote_preserved_split(line):
    """The Regex preserve outer quotes and also the escape characters"""
    return re.findall("(?:\".*?[^\\\]\"|\S)+", line)

with open(file='firewall_policy.conf', mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

for i in range(len(lines)):
    line = lines[i].strip()
    if line.startswith('set'):
        print(quote_preserved_split(line))
```

Output:

```
['set', 'name', '"policy 168"']
['set', 'uuid', '14435052-3097-4d70-98c7-1dd2d60e229f']
['set', 'srcintf', '"jimmylin__1688"']
['set', 'dstintf', '"port1"']
['set', 'srcaddr', '"address__jimmylin__10.100.168.11/32"']
['set', 'dstaddr', '"all"']
['set', 'action', 'accept']
['set', 'schedule', '"always"']
['set', 'service', '"ALL"']
['set', 'comments', '"\\"customer\\": \\"Jimmy Lin\\""']
['set', 'nat', 'enable']
['set', 'ippool', 'enable']
['set', 'poolname', '"ippool__jimmylin__168.100.168.11"']
```

Joining each line by using `join()` you get :

```
set name "policy 168"
set uuid 14435052-3097-4d70-98c7-1dd2d60e229f
set srcintf "jimmylin__1688"
set dstintf "port1"
set srcaddr "address__jimmylin__10.100.168.11/32"
set dstaddr "all"
set action accept
set schedule "always"
set service "ALL"
set comments "\"customer\": \"Jimmy Lin\""
set nat enable
set ippool enable
set poolname "ippool__jimmylin__168.100.168.11"
```

Comment: Thank you for the replying. I appreciate it, but in fact I've showed this way in my post (shlex_split wtih absent posix, and posix's default value is True). Maybe my post is too long and messy, sorry for that.

Comment: With this way we can join it back together with shlex.join, but when it comes to string like lines[10] in my post, the double quotes around the "ALL" would disappear.

Comment: oh so you want the double quotes everywhere to be there as it is. ok. will try.

Comment: @林敬智 check for edited answer with `regex`. I haven't found any solution with `shlex` yet. I think it may be difficult with that.

Comment: @林敬智 Improved edited answer with `shlex` too. check it out.

Comment: Thank you so much for these solutions. Both method are truly something great, but I need some time to figure them out. It seem like you are familiar with the shlex module, I cannot use it like what you did in your answer - using the shlex class itself and its instance, changing some attributes of it and output the result. The output of regex method looks like exact what I want, but I need some time to test it with other input. Thank you for your replying again. I'll see this as the answer but If I find anything I'll share with you!

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is: "..to get it into python so then we can do all the data-processing things around it" and you do not mind using other Python libraries, you might want to have a look at [TTP](https://github.com/dmulyalin/ttp) and this code sample:

```
from ttp import ttp
import pprint

data = """
config firewall policy
    edit 168
        set name "policy 168"
        set uuid 14435052-3097-4d70-98c7-1dd2d60e229f
        set srcintf "jimmylin__1688"
        set dstintf "port1"
        set srcaddr "address__jimmylin__10.100.168.11/32"
        set dstaddr "all"
        set action accept
        set schedule "always"
        set service "ALL"
        set comments "\"customer\": \"Jimmy Lin\""
        set nat enable
        set ippool enable
        set poolname "ippool__jimmylin__168.100.168.11"
    next
    edit 200
        set name "policy 200"
        set uuid 14435052-3097-4d70-98c7-1dd2d60e2200
        set srcintf "jimmylin__16"
        set dstintf "port2"
    next
end
"""

template = """
<group name="policies**">
config firewall policy {{ _start_ }}
    <group name="{{ name }}**">
    edit {{ id }}
        set name "{{ name | ORPHRASE }}"
        set uuid {{ uuid }}
        set srcintf "{{ srcintf }}"
        set dstintf "{{ dstintf }}"
        set srcaddr "{{ srcaddr }}"
        set dstaddr "{{ dstaddr }}"
        set action {{ action }}
        set schedule "{{ schedule}}"
        set service "{{ service}}"
        set comments {{ comments | ORPHRASE | replace('"', '') }}
        set nat enable {{ nat_enabled | set(True) }}
        set ippool enable {{ ippool_enabled | set(True) }}
        set poolname "{{ poolname }}"    
    next {{ _end_ }}
    </group>
end {{ _end_ }}
</group>
"""

parser = ttp(data, template)
parser.parse()
res = parser.result()
pprint.pprint(res, width=100)

# will print:
# [[{'policies': {'policy 168': {'action': 'accept',
#                                'comments': 'customer: Jimmy Lin',
#                                'dstaddr': 'all',
#                                'dstintf': 'port1',
#                                'id': '168',
#                                'ippool_enabled': True,
#                                'nat_enabled': True,
#                                'poolname': 'ippool__jimmylin__168.100.168.11',
#                                'schedule': 'always',
#                                'service': 'ALL',
#                                'srcaddr': 'address__jimmylin__10.100.168.11/32',
#                                'srcintf': 'jimmylin__1688',
#                                'uuid': '14435052-3097-4d70-98c7-1dd2d60e229f'},
#                 'policy 200': {'dstintf': 'port2',
#                                'id': '200',
#                                'srcintf': 'jimmylin__16',
#                                'uuid': '14435052-3097-4d70-98c7-1dd2d60e2200'}}}]]
```

Comment: Hello, sorry I didn't see the post. Thanks a lot. This may helps, I didn't know there is a package like this. The usage is very easy to understand. Now I've been working on with the shlex way already, but I will check this later. Thank you very much!